# Single XML, Multiple Activity & there Performance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I have some simple **questions** for **Android Users**.

1. If I use `Single XML` for `Multiple Activity`, What issues might come ??
2. **How it ll help in Application PERFORMANCE**, if we use this kind of approach ??

for example : If have same `XML layouts` **A,B,C** for **A,B,C** `Activity`, Instead of using multiple layout I want to use only single Layout i.e. **A** `XML Layout`  for **A,B,C** `Activity`.

**Note: I have tried this, works fine. But I want to know that any issues or problem using this kind of approach. Gone through some sites but din't get cleared picture**

Suggestions or help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks ..!!

Comment: no issue,you can access the views inside individual activity.no probs. :)

Comment: @AndroidKiller : it ll help in reducing the memory ??

Comment: It shouldn't reduce memory; the inflated layout is independent for each activity. But it will make maintenance easier.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield , your right, it ll be easier to maintain.

Comment: @TechEnd just reduce memory because it willl not let you create another xml file, but that much of memory doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it wont help to reduce the memory . because usually you wont show same contents in all the activities. you will do visible and visiblegone.. for some layout.. those functions will change according to activity.

Comment: @AndroidKiller In what sense it is good for using different layouts and single layouts (instead of maintaince).

Comment: @Rajesh I agree we wont show same content. But in some apps you can use same multiple layouts. For Example I am creating an app in which is fetching data from server to listview. I have same layouts for 3 diff activities

Comment: @TechEnd Yeah for ListView,GridView,Gallery We can you same layout files. and also If you are using footer or Top Tablayout means you can use commonly use through out the app.

Comment: @TechEnd,For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem at all. The XML will get inflated as separate instances for each Activity.

Note that because they are separate instances, any data on those forms won't be shared between them, though; you would need to pass data between activities as extras on an intent or through a persistence mechanism (databases, shared prefs, etc)

Comment: yaa we have to send data using extras on an intent from one activity to another activity.

Comment: I think there's a slight performance advantage, as I believe I read that Android does cache at least some XML files that it reads.